# Como puedo obtener por consola el nombre y precio de los articulos seleccionados en JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

como puedo obtener el nombre y precio de los artículos, de un campo checked por consola en jquery.

Tengo un html con un input, span(nombre del articulo), y otro span(con el precio del articulo). ¿como puedo obtener los valores de estos por jquery?

Luego tengo esta función donde quiero obtener el nombre y precio del articulo por consola, pero al seleccionar el botón me sale on

```js
function cogerSeleccionados() {
  let nombreArticulo;
  $("#agregarCarrito").click(function() {
    $('input:checked ').each(function(posicion, valor) {
      $(".nombreArticulos").val(nombreArticulo);
    });
    console.log(nombreArticulo);
    /*             alert("Number of selected Languages: " + selectedLanguage.length + "\n" + "And, they are: " + selectedLanguage);
     */
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">

  <div><input name="ps5" type="checkbox" data-com.bitwarden.browser.user-edited="yes"><span class="nombreArticulos">Playstation 5 - </span><span class="precio">779.90</span></div>
  <div><input name="tv" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">TV Xiaomi 43" - </span><span class="precio">399.00</span></div>
  <div><input name="nevera" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Nevera Samsung - </span><span class="precio">1099.95</span></div>
  <div><input name="lavadora" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Lavadora/Secadora Balay - </span><span class="precio">1074.95</span></div>
  <div><input name="xbox" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Xbox Series S - </span><span class="precio">299.95</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de este modo, sin tener que modificar el HTML y basándote en la disposición actual de tu HTML:

```js
$("#agregarCarrito").click(function() {
  let nombreArticulo = ''
  let precioArticulo = ''
  let carrito = []
  $('input:checked ').each(function(posicion, valor) {
    nombreArticulo = ($(this).closest("div").find(".nombreArticulos").html());
    precioArticulo = ($(this).closest("div").find(".precio").html());
    console.log(nombreArticulo)
    console.log(precioArticulo)

    carrito.push([nombreArticulo, precioArticulo])
  });
  console.log(carrito)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">

  <div><input name="ps5" type="checkbox" data-com.bitwarden.browser.user-edited="yes"><span class="nombreArticulos">Playstation 5 - </span><span class="precio">779.90</span></div>
  <div><input name="tv" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">TV Xiaomi 43" - </span><span class="precio">399.00</span></div>
  <div><input name="nevera" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Nevera Samsung - </span><span class="precio">1099.95</span></div>
  <div><input name="lavadora" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Lavadora/Secadora Balay - </span><span class="precio">1074.95</span></div>
  <div><input name="xbox" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Xbox Series S - </span><span class="precio">299.95</span></div>
</div>
<button id="agregarCarrito">
Agregar carrito
</button>
```

donde usamos el método [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para situarnos en el div padre del checkbox seleccionado, y desde alli buscamos, con el método [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) las clases de los span que contienen el nombre del artículo y su precio dentro del mismo div, y lo agregamos a una variable carrito de forma conjunta correlacionándolos entre si para un posible uso posterior.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

usas los atributos `name` y `value` de tu checkbox para guardar la informacion (nombre y valor), posteriormente el `button` de buscar productos hara una busqueda de los `checkbox` activos en el div de inputs y extraera los atributos con jquery, y ademas en la misma funcion he creado un arreglo de objetos con los productos seleccionados espero te sirva.

```js
function buscarArticulos(){
//Busca los checkbox en estado checked
    let inputCheck =      $("#divInputs").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    //Extrae la informacion de los checkbox encontrados
    let elementos = inputCheck.map((index,item)=>{
      return {
        nombreProducto: $(item).attr('name'),
        precio: $(item).val()
      }
    })
    //Muestra la informacion de los productos seleccionados.
    console.info(elementos)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divInputs" class="inputs">
  <div><input name="Playstation 5" value="779.90" type="checkbox" data-com.bitwarden.browser.user-edited="yes"><span class="nombreArticulos">Playstation 5 - </span><span class="precio">779.90</span></div>
  <div><input name="TV Xiaomi 43" value="399.00"  type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">TV Xiaomi 43" - </span><span class="precio">399.00</span></div>
  <div><input name="Nevera Samsung" value="1099.95" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Nevera Samsung - </span><span class="precio">1099.95</span></div>
  <div><input  name="Lavadora/Secadora Balay" value="1074.95" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Lavadora/Secadora Balay - </span><span class="precio">1074.95</span></div>
  <div><input name="Xbox Series S" value="299.95" type="checkbox"><span class="nombreArticulos">Xbox Series S - </span><span class="precio">299.95</span></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="buscarArticulos()"> buscar</button>
```